# Show that $T:P_m\times P_n \to P_{m+n}$ where $T(p,q) = fp + gq$ is onto if and only if $f$ and $g$ have no common roots.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Given that $P_k$ is the vector space of complex polynomials of degree less than $k$, and $f,g$ are monic polynomials of degree $m,n$ respectively, I need to show that the linear transformation $T:P_m\times P_n \to P_{m+n}$ where $T(p,q) = fp + gq$ is onto if and only if $f$ and $g$ have no common roots.

I tried showing the contrapositive of the forward direction which says that if $f,g$ *do* have a root in common, then $L$ cannot be onto.

**Here is my attempt**: Suppose $f,g$ have the root $z\in\mathbb C$ in common. Then we know that $f(z) = g(z) = 0$, so in such case we have $T(p,q) = 0$ for all $p,q$.

**Here's my question**: Can I say that since the linear transformation always yields $0$ for such a $z$, then not all polynomials in the codomain can be reached by something from the domain, which implies $T$ is not onto? If so, then I am done with the forward direction.

The backwards direction is somewhat harder as well. I would have to show that if $T$ is not onto, then $f,g$ have a root in common. A function that is *not* onto would mean that there is a polynomial in the codomain $P_{m+n}$ such that no pair of polynomials will map to it from the domain. I was inclined to believe it might be easy and have a similar result from above, but I'm having some trouble making the connection. Obviously we could pull $(p,q) = (0,0)\in P_m\times P_n$, which would guaranteed map to $0$ in the codomain, but that will tell us nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement of the proof of the forward direction is wrong: it is not true that $T(p,q)=0$. This means, that $T(p,q)$ is the zero polynomial, which in general is not the case. However we have $T(p,q)(z)=0$, which proves that the image of $T$ consists of polynomials possessing the zero $z$ only. Thus the constant polynomial $1$ is not in that image, hence $T$ is not surjective.

To prove that $T$ is surjective if $f$ and $g$ have no common root you need to use the so called Theorem of Bezout for the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$: it tells you that the greatest common divisor $\mathrm{gcd}(f,g)$ of two polynomials is a linear combination of the polynomials

$\mathrm{gcd}(f,g)=uf+vg$

for some $u,v\in\mathbb{C}[x]$. Now if $f$ and $g$ have no common root $ \mathrm{gcd}(f,g)=1$, that is $1$ is in the image of $T$. The map $T$ has the property $T(rp,rq)=rT(p,q)$, hence proving that $1$ is in the image implies surjectivity.